# Python method for any integer returns a list consisting of numbers 5 and 7 only

Tags: python

Develop a Python method that for any integer amount in the range from 24 to 1000 returns a list consisting of numbers 5 and 7 only, such that their sum is equal to amount. For example, `change(28)` may return `[7, 7, 7, 7]`, while `change(49)` may return `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]` or `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7]` or `[7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]`

i tried :

```
def change(amount):
  if amount == 24:
    return [5, 5, 7, 7]

change(24)
print (amount)
```

but i think there is more efficient way to do the trick.. any help?

Comment: Please use proper formatting. Also your code doesn't seem to make any sense. Instead of just pasting your code here, please try to explain why you coded in that manner.

Comment: you need some basic understanding of how algorithms work and how to solve problems like yours using a algorithm. Reading or following a tutorial online is a good start ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in your code at line `print (amount)` because `amount` is not defined in the global scope, it is only defined as a local parameter of `change()` function.  You should write `print(change(24))` instead.

Secondly, your code manages only the input amount 24, nothing else. You have to design an algorithm to do the trick for any input number. With Python you can do it in a straightforward way to find a pair of numbers (i,j) for which i*5+j*7 == amount. You can check this equality for any pair value: i from 0 to amount, and j from 0 to amount, for example.  Once this equality is found, then you can build the list with 5s and 7s and return.

Practically in Python:

- to loop with i from 0 to amount-1: `for i in range(amount):`
- to loop with j from 0 to amount-1: `for j in range(amount):`
- to check the equality: `if (i*5)+(j*7) == amount:`
- to build and return the list: `return [5]*i + [7]*j`

Obviously you have to learn the **basics of Python** to use this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just start to code in Python then the code below is built for you. Maybe it is not exceptionally  sophisticated but it is understandable for any beginner:

```
def five_and_seven_list(number):
    if number < 24 or number > 1000:
        return False

    elif number % 7 == 0:
        result = []
        start = int(number / 7)
        for i in range(start, 0,-1):
            result.append(7)
        return result

    elif number % 5 == 0:
        result = []
        start=int(number / 5)
        for i in range(start, 0,-1):
            result.append(5)
        return result
    else:
        end=0
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if (number - i) % 10 == 0:
                end = i
                break

        if end == 1:
            result = [7, 7, 7]

        if end == 6 or end == 2 or end == 7:
            result = [7, 5]

        if end == 4:
            result = [7, 7]

        if end == 8:
            result = [7, 7, 7, 7]

        if end == 3:
            result = [7, 7, 7, 7, 5]

        if end == 9:
            result = [7, 7, 5]

        left = int((number - sum(result)) / 5)

        while left > 0:
            left -= 1
            result.append(5)

        return result

print(five_and_seven_list(28),five_and_seven_list(49),five_and_seven_list(47))
```

the output is:

```
[7, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Looping the first number with x in amount which is presented here: `for x in range(amount):`
2. Looping the second number with y in amount which is presented here: `for y in range(amount):`
3. The if statement is provided to show if x * 5 + y * 7 is equivalent to the functions parameter given: `if (x*5)+(y*7) == amount:`
4. Last but not least we return our proven equivalence so when we call the function it will show the listed 5s and 7s that is the sum of the amount given in our function: `return [5]*x + [7]*y`

Code should look like this more or less:

```
def change(amount): 
    for x in range(amount): 
        for y in range(amount):
            if (x*5)+(y*7) == amount:
                return [5]*x + [7]*y
```